# Can PiTest produce reports in JSON instead of HTML? or is there Data Scraper code for PiTest reports available?

Tags: pitest

I want Pitest reports in JSON format. Is there any way I can create them in JSON? or is there a data scraper code for Pitest reports in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pitest has built in support to generate

- HTML
- XML
- CSV

HTML is generated by default, other formats can be specified using the `outputFormats` parameter.

The HTML output is special in that it incorporates line coverage data, the others only contain mutation results.

Pitest has a plugin system. Support for additional formats such as json can be added by implementing a `MutationResultsListener`.

https://pitest.org/quickstart/advanced/